# Error while installing ESXi 5

Tags: vmware-workstation, esxi

Just wanted to install ESXi 5 under VMware Workstation 8 and I get the following error:

[image: ESXi 5 error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added some memory 2GB, and it works fine

[Minimum requirement: 2GB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003661)